# How can I position a GameObject with the help of a Ray?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

For my grid-based game I want the enemies to have a line of sight that is visible to the player. The enemies can only look in one direction (up, down, left or right) and they won't change that direction once set.

The enemies cannot look through Obstacles or other Enemies, which is why I have set up a Raycast. This Raycast detects if the Player is in a direct line to the direction of the Enemy.
This is my EnemySight Scrip:

```
PathFollower pathFollower;

    public GameObject sightline;
    public GameObject player;

    float rayLength = 20f;

    bool onSameZAxis = false;

    Ray myRay;
    RaycastHit hit;

    void Start()
    {
        GameObject g = GameObject.Find("Path");
        pathFollower = g.GetComponent<PathFollower>();

    }

    void Update()
    {
        DrawRay();

        if (player.transform.position.z.Equals(transform.position.z) && pathFollower.hasCheckedAxis == false)
        {
            onSameZAxis = true;
        }
        else { onSameZAxis = false; }

        //checks only when enemy stands still if the player is in sight and on same axis
        if (onSameZAxis == true && pathFollower.standsStill == true && PlayerInSight() == true)
        {
            Debug.Log("spotted");
            pathFollower.sawPlayer = true;
            pathFollower.hasCheckedAxis = true;
            //onSameZAxis = false;
            //Debug.Log("In the If-Loop");

        }

    }


    //checks if there is a wall between the player and the enemy
    bool PlayerInSight()
    {
        myRay = new Ray(transform.position + new Vector3(0, 0.15f, 0), -transform.right);

        Debug.DrawRay(myRay.origin, myRay.direction, Color.red);

        if (Physics.Raycast(myRay, out hit, rayLength))
        {
            if (hit.collider.tag == "Player")
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    void DrawRay()
    {
        //Moves the Sightline Object.
    }
}
```

I have made the Sightline GameObject a Child of the respective enemy, so it moves with the enemy. The problem is that it will move through Obstacles and Enemies, altough the player won't be detected then.

I was thinking about moving the pivot point of my Sightline GameObject to the Vector 3 hit of the Raycast but I don't know how that could work.

I'm happy about any suggestions or solutions, thank you in advance!

Comment: Not exactly what you need, but check this out https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rQG9aUWarwE

Comment: That could work actually, thank you very much!